# Xcode - How to change place of Tab Bar Item

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I want the Contact icon on the left, what is the easiest way to do this?

[image]

EDIT: I found a simple solution.. I just had to delete the link between my Tab Bar Controller and the Bookmark page, then reconnect it to set it as second icon (on the right). See image: prntscr.com/b0hucd

Comment: go to storyboard and shift your tab index

Comment: I found a simple solution.. I just had to delete the link between my Tab Bar Controller and the Bookmark page, then reconnect it to set it as second icon (on the right).

See image: http://prntscr.com/b0hucd

Comment: please answer your own question then. would help others

Answer (score 7):

Drag and drop should work

You can drag the contacts bar Item to the left  to rearrange its position from the Storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code i used it to move the image in tabbar items to move vertically up.In this loop check that the index is 1 else it will move the bookmark icon also

```
for (UITabBarItem * item in tabBarController.tabBar.items) {
        item.image=[item.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
        item.imageInsets=UIEdgeInsetsMake(item.imageInsets.top, item.imageInsets.left+20, item.imageInsets.bottom, item.imageInsets.right-20);
    }
```

Note: If it doesn't move the text let me know

Comment: Found a better solution, look my answer above :)

Answer (score 0):

[UITabBar Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBar_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBar/items)

Check out the "items" property. (emphasis mine)

> This property contains an array of UITabBarItem objects, each of which corresponds to a tab displayed by the tab bar. **The order of the items in this property corresponds to the order of the items onscreen.** You can use this property to access the items as needed.